# Poor large transfers behind NAT on Centos

Tags: networking, centos, nat

I have the following set up.

A Centos 6.5 VM running on an ESX host, with a public IP4 address.  It is acting as a gateway for (a bunch of) other Centos 6.5 VMs that are only connected to a virtual network.

Connectivity is working fine.

However, I trying to perform large uploads from the VMs on the virtual network, eg. uploading to S3 or using rsync to rsync.net gets very slow bandwidth (~30kB\s)

Running exactly the same commands on the gateway host directly gives about 3MB\s

Download speeds on the other VMs appears to be unaffected (certiainly not an order of magnitude let alone 2)

Copying between the VMs happens at full speed

The gateway host is basically idle, has no other duties and plenty of free memory.

Any suggestions on a cause or how to go about trouble shooting this?

Thanks.